# Problem setting video frame rate using AVAssetWriter/AVAssetReader

Tags: ios, swift, macos, video, video-encoding

### Situation:

I am trying to export video with some parameters like video bit rate, audio bit rate, frame rate, changing video resolution, etc. Note that I am letting the user set the video frame rate in fractions; like user can set the video frame rate say, 23.98.

I use **AVAssetWriter** and **AVAssetReader** for this operation. I use [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinputpixelbufferadaptor) for writing the sample buffers.

Everything else works just fine, except the **video frame rate**.

### What I have tried:

1. Setting the **AVAssetWriter.movieTimeScale** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16911799/1208191). Which does change the video frame rate but also makes the video sluggish. ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/chauhan130/31b8bf648f0071a949d1627c78315056#file-gistfile1-txt-L16))

---

2. Setting **AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey**. Which does not help. ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/chauhan130/31b8bf648f0071a949d1627c78315056#file-gistfile1-txt-L38))

---

3. Setting **AVAssetWriterInput.mediaTimeScale**. Again, it changes the video frame rate but makes the video sluggish as *AVAssetWriter.movieTimeScale* does. The video shows different frames at some point and sometimes it sticks and resumes again. ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/chauhan130/31b8bf648f0071a949d1627c78315056#file-gistfile1-txt-L50))

---

4. Using **AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput** and setting **AVMutableVideoComposition.frameDuration**; just like [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) does. Ironically with SDAVAssetExportSession code, the video is being exported just at the right frame rate that I want, but it just does not work in my code. [gist here](https://gist.github.com/chauhan130/8d2f5bbe680353961fecacb80e254b92#file-gistfile1-txt-L77)

I am not sure why it won't work with my code. The issue with this approach is it always returns nil from *AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()*.

---

5. Manually changing the timestamp of the frame with **CMSampleTimingInfo**, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236475/1208191) Something like:

```
var sampleTimingInfo = CMSampleTimingInfo()
var sampleBufferToWrite: CMSampleBuffer?

CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(vBuffer, at: 0, timingInfoOut: &sampleTimingInfo)

sampleTimingInfo.duration = CMTimeMake(value: 100, timescale: Int32(videoConfig.videoFrameRate * 100))

sampleTimingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeAdd(previousPresentationTimeStamp, sampleTimingInfo.duration)

previousPresentationTimeStamp = sampleTimingInfo.presentationTimeStamp

let status = CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer: vBuffer,sampleTimingEntryCount: 1, sampleTimingArray: &sampleTimingInfo, sampleBufferOut: &sampleBufferToWrite)
```

With this approach, I do get the frame rate set just right, but it increases the video duration (as mentioned in the comment of that question’s answer). I think at some point I may have to discard some frames (if the target frame rate is lower; I need to lower the frame rate in most of the cases).

If I know that if I want 30fps, and my current frame rate is 60fps, it's simple to discard every second frame and setting the SampleBuffer time accordingly.

If I go with this approach(i.e. setting 23.98 fps), how do I decide which frame to discard and if the target frame rate is higher, which frame to duplicate? Reminder: the frame rate could be in fractions.

---

Comment: Hmm if you are aiming for arbitrary framerates, wouldn't it make sense to first upsample (filter) the video to a much higher fps (say 120 or more)  and then downsample to the correct fps? This may keep the smoothness of the motion intact, while just skipping every n frames will totally destroy the pace of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to select frames. Suppose the fps of source video is F and target fps is TF. rate = TF/F

Initiate a variable n equal to -rate and add rate each time,
when the integer part of n changed, select the frame.

```
e.g. rate = 0.3
          n: -0.3 0 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2 1.5 1.8 2.1
                  ^              ^           ^
frame index:      0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
select 0 4 7
```

```
float rate = 0.39999f; // TF/F 
float n =  -rate; // to make sure first frame will be selected
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i, n += rate) { // i stands for frame index, take a video with 100 frames as an example
    int m = floor(n);
    int tmp = n+rate;
    // if rate > 1.0 repeat i
    // if rate < 1.0 some of the frames will be dropped
    for (int j = 0; m+j < tmp; ++j) {
        // Use this frame
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableDictionary *writerInputParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[writerInputParams setObject:AVVideoCodecTypeH264 forKey:AVVideoCodecKey];
[writerInputParams setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:width] forKey:AVVideoWidthKey];
[writerInputParams setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height] forKey:AVVideoHeightKey];
[writerInputParams setObject:AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill forKey:AVVideoScalingModeKey];
NSMutableDictionary * compressionProperties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[compressionProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 20] forKey:AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey];
[compressionProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 20] forKey:AVVideoAverageNonDroppableFrameRateKey];
[compressionProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0.0] forKey:AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalDurationKey];
[compressionProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey];
[compressionProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey];
[compressionProperties setObject:AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel forKey:AVVideoProfileLevelKey];
[writerInputParams setObject:compressionProperties forKey:AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey];

self.assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:writerInputParams];
self.assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
```

It has been verified that SCNView refreshes 60 frames per second, but using AVAssetWriter only wants to save 20 frames per second, what should to do?

Neither AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey nor AVVideoAverageNonDroppableFrameRateKey above will not affect fps, config fps will not work !!!
// Set this to make sure that a functional movie is produced, even if the recording is cut off mid-stream. Only the last second should be lost in that case.
self.videoWriter.movieFragmentInterval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1000);
self.videoWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
self.videoWriter.movieTimeScale = 20;
The above configuration will not affect fps either.

```
self.assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:writerInputParams];
self.assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
/// this config will change video frame presenttime to fit fps, but it will be change video duration.
```

// self.assetWriterInput.mediaTimeScale = 20;
self.assetWriterInput.mediaTimeScale will affect the fps, but will cause the video duration to be stretched by 3 times, because
BOOL isSUc = [self.writerAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:cvBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime]; The time of the filled frame will be re-modified, so the self.assetWriterInput.mediaTimeScale value is configured, which is seriously inconsistent with expectations, and the video duration should not be stretched.

So if you want to control the fps of the video that AVAssetWriter finally saves, you must pass the control, and must make sure call 20 per second.

```
CMTime presentationTime = CMTimeMake(_writeCount * (1.0/20.0) * 1000, 1000);
BOOL isSUc = [self.writerAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:cvBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];
_writeCount += 1;
```